# can't initiate nested block on iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, ios8, objective-c-blocks

I am trying to do a nested block inside of another block.  It seems that possibly asynchronous requests time out a lot fast on iOS8 as opposed to previous version of iOS.  Here is my Parse code:

```
- (void)getRemoteImageAndSaveLocalWithObjectId:(NSString *)objectId andType:(NSString *)type{
    if ([type isEqualToString:@"user"]) {
        PFQuery *query = [GAUser query];
        //[query includeKey:@"userImage"];
        [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:objectId block:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
            GAUser *gaUser = (GAUser *)object;
            PFFile *userImageFile = gaUser[@"@userImage"];

            [userImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {

                // I am never able to get inside this block of code.
                NSLog(@"in get data");
                if (!error) {

                    NSLog(@"remote image name: %@",data.debugDescription);

                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];


                }else{

                    NSLog(@"there was an error");
                }
            }];


        }];
    }

}
```

Does anyone know why I can't get in the `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` block?

Comment: Is `userImageFile` nil?

Comment: It is nil or not PFFile

Answer (score 0):

Darren and Andy were right (they're probably brothers).

userImageFile was nil and that was the problem.